# Correct way to make Left Join on two Streams in Apache Flink

Tags: stream, left-join, apache-flink

I'm working on a fraud detection system using Apache Flink but I'm a beginner and am stuck on this problem:

I want to make a Left Join from two Streams, one that contains a current transaction and other that has validated transactions with the bank where I can find if there have been some errors like stolen_card, etc. So I need to join them to know if a card has been declined in the past.

```
   DataStream<Card> currentDataStream =  getCardsStream(env, Parameters.CURRENT_SOCKET)
            .keyBy((card) -> card.getCardID);

    DataStream<Card> historicDataStream =  getCardsStream(env, Parameters.HISTORIC_SOCKET)
            .keyBy((card) -> card.getCardID());
```

What I'm doing right now is a RichCoFlatMapFunction that updates a List State called **historicList** each time a historicDataStream arrives and returning a tuple with the current card and a List with all the joined occurrences for that Id:

```
public class LeftJoin extends RichCoFlatMapFunction<Card, Card, Tuple2<Card, List<Card>> > {

    private ValueState<Card> currentValueState;
    private ListState<Card> historicListState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        currentValueState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("Current State", Card.class));
        historicListState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(new ListStateDescriptor<>("historic state", Card.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Card currentCard, Collector<Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>> out) throws Exception {
        Iterable<Card> historicCardList =  historicListState.get();

        //If there is a coincidence
        if (Iterables.size(historicCardList) > 0) {
            out.collect(new Tuple2<>(currentCard, Lists.newArrayList(historicCardList) ));
        } else {
            currentValueState.update(currentCard);
            //Returning null if there are no cards for the Id
            out.collect(new Tuple2<>(currentCard, null));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Card historicCard, Collector<Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>> out) throws Exception {
        historicListState.add(historicCard); //Updates the historicListState
    }
}
```

The thing is that the `List<Card>` is causing me a lot of trouble later when I want to check rules against the contained Cards because it always gets all the cards again, and I need a way to mark the cards that I already processed against my rules, something like this:

```
  //I don't like this list because it always gets me all the join coincidences
    for (Card card : historicList) {

        //Comparar cada regla del Broadcast state con el error que contiene el elemento card
        if (rule.getBankDecision().equals(card.getErrors())) {


            //Evaluate some rules
            for (Long stateEventTime : windowState.keys()) {
                if (isStateValueInWindow(stateEventTime, windowStartForEvent, System.currentTimeMillis())) {
                    aggregateValuesInState(stateEventTime, aggregator);
                }

            }
    }
```

Is there a better way to get the Joined Cards as a Stream?

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand you correctly, if not please recorrect me.

1. `private ValueState<Card> currentValueState` is redundent (in this example you only update it and never read it`s value)
2. If i understand you correctly, the problem is that you emit your RuleSystem on whole historicListState altaugh you checked some of them already. 
   why not delete from historicListState cards that already past the rules?